# AsyncTask stop working android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

Im using lots of AsyncTask for searching,parsing and more in my application. I use AsyncTask because i need to update ui before and after and it pretty easy with it.

The problem is when im proberly using new thread while the old ones didn't die properly and then the thread stop working.

How can i avoid this problem?

Comment: the using of the thread is realy stright forward. i don't do anyting magical :) i read somewhere that there is a thread limit for app? Also i can see in debuging mode that the thread riched to it end and "die"

Answer (score 1):

May be a better way of doing it is, following a sequential process? Something like this

You start the second asynctask in the onPostExecute() of first. Similarly you start the 3rd asynctask in onPostexecute of second.
So that way, you have more control over it, and the memory is managed well (even in devices having lesser memory).

Thanks

Comment: The thread may happen in different activities and not always related to each other. example:
1) parsing file 2)update ui. and do this thread 10 times and it stop working

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use signals .  i like to use [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) where you can initialize your latch in one thread and count down it in once it is about to complete the task ., On other thread call `await()` which will be blocked until previous thread doesn't call `countDown()`.

Comment: It sound like a good way but is it make sure threads are dead?